# `cannot load AppArmor profile` on `minikube start`

Tags: linux, ubuntu

## Environment

- OS: Linux
- Distribution: Ubuntu 18.10
- Minikube version: 0.30.0
- Minikube Installation method: `.deb` package: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/download/v0.30.0/minikube_0.30-0.deb

## Question

I get the following error:

```
$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E1121 09:39:27.090220    3560 start.go:168] Error starting host: Error starting stopped host: Error creating VM: virError(Code=1, Domain=24, Message='internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-967dddb2-a13b-4f9a-9e58-7852bb849c72'').

 Retrying.
E1121 09:39:27.090477    3560 start.go:174] Error starting host:  Error starting stopped host: Error creating VM: virError(Code=1, Domain=24, Message='internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-967dddb2-a13b-4f9a-9e58-7852bb849c72'')
```

Is someone able to understand the problem?

Disabling `AppArmor` might solve it, but this is not a good solution IMO.

Comment: Possibly a lot more people with minikube expertise on StackOverflow (where discussing software used in the development cycle is on-topic).

Comment: @xenoid mmmh IMO this is more on-topic here